# Bootstrap weird behavior on screen width smaller than 480px

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this website working as expected on desktop and wider devices, however when viewing on screens smaller than about 480px, it looks like the body width gets scaled down.

It gets worse as the screen gets smaller:
[image: This is the problem]

Because the CSS is so huge and multiple files get combined, I wouldn't even know what code to post here.

Hopefully someone can find the problem by having a look: http://www.sportbijwillem.nl

I appreciate any help.

Comment: My guess it has something to do with your `badgehead` and `badgetext` elements being `absolute` positioned and have a static width. So what you're seeing is the browser trying to render the full width of those elements - so it looks like the content box is smaller than it should be, when it's actually the `badgecont` and its children messing it up.

Comment: @disinfor You are correct. Those were indeed messing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There are multiple mistakes:

1. You have commented out `width: 100%;` of the `img` with class `.badgeback`. The Image should have the `width: 100%;`.
2. `.badgehead` and  `.badgetext` have fixed width of `390px`, which is wider than the viewport. Try giving width in percentage. Like give both `width: 100%;`
3. `.badgehead` and  `.badgetext` also have fixed `left` value `left: 249px;` which is very  very high, thus they push the content out. Try giving them `left: 180px;`.

***Second and Third should only be followed with `media queries`.***

Comment: Thanks! You got me on the right track. The badge was indeed the problem.